# $f^{-1}(E^c)=(f^{-1}(E))^c$ if $f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am just stuck with proving how $f^{-1}(E^c)=(f^{-1}(E))^c$ when $f$ is continuous. Can this be true if $f$ is not continuous? Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As the pre-image operator $f^{-1}[\cdot]$ commutes with almost every set-operation, this is true, and is purely set-theoretic, i. e. does not depend on the topology and continuity. Note that we have for $f \colon A \to B$ and arbitrary $E \subseteq B$, $a \in A$:
\begin{align*}
  a \in f^{-1}[E^c] &\iff f(a) \in E^c \\
                    &\iff \neg \bigl(f(a) \in E\bigr)\\
                    &\iff \neg \bigl(a \in f^{-1}[E]\bigr)\\
                    &\iff a \in f^{-1}[E]^c
\end{align*}